# How to make my last Worlds copy to the first in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, notepad

So i need help
I want to copy all my last word to the first word
example:

```
^=/system/priv-app/Hearingdro_Tablet_V4_N
^=/system/priv-app/SetupWizard
^=/system/priv-app/ANTRadioService
```

to:

```
Hearingdro_Tablet_V4_N^=/system/priv-app/Hearingdro_Tablet_V4_N
Hearingdro_Tablet_V4_N^=/system/priv-app/Hearingdro_Tablet_V4_N
SetupWizard^=/system/priv-app/SetupWizard
ANTRadioService^=/system/priv-app/ANTRadioService
```

Anybody know how???

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

- Find what: `^(.*?/)(\w+$)`
- Replace with: `\2\1\2`
- Search mode: Regular expression

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go with only one capture group, more efficient.

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*/(\w+)$`
- Replace with: `$1$0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .*        # 0 or more any character but newline
  /         # a slash
  (\w+)     # group 1, 1 or more word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, the last word
$0          # the whole match
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]